# Vue bind without colon or shorthand

Tags: vue.js, react-dom-server

Vue has any way to don't use the shorthand or colon? this is not valid html and I have problems implementing it with React-Dom for server rendering in Node.js

[image: error]

Comment: This is unfortunately the problem when using vue templates with an existing templating engine, a problem which Single File Components circumvent.

Comment: className also isn't valid HTML attribute.
You should switch to other server side rendering engine than React-Dom. 
Consider Nuxt.js or take a look how they do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue 2.4.0+ syntax can be used:

```
<a v-on="{click:myFunc}" ...
```

For this syntax `passive`, `once` and `capture` modifiers can be assigned using `&`, `~` and `!` prefixes correspondingly
([Event & Key Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Event-amp-Key-Modifiers)).

Other modifiers aren't implemented yet
(see this issue: [Extending object syntax of v-on to support modifiers #7846](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7846)).

Answer (score 4):

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand

There are 2 important shorthand notations:

`<div :value="true"></div>` means `<div v-bind:value="true"></div>`

`<div @click="myFunc"></div>` means `<div v-on:click="myFunc"></div>`

So you can use both interchangeably.

It might not work in your case, i have not yet tried to mix react-dom and vue together.